# Custom view and main activity

Tags: android

i want to use a point array in custom view which is in different class . but that point array is actually declared in main activity . and custom view only extends view so when i use the point array in ondraw() it is undeclared .

Actually i want coordinates in an array in ondraw() function and then use them in my main activity where rest of my code resides . and then i also want to add button on that view.

Q2. i used another approach where i didn't make new java file for custom view and tried to add two linear layouts in main.xml one for button and one for custom view but here when i load the view which is in main activity it dont get load what will be the syntax thanks .

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.faisal.FaisalActivity.DemoView
        android:id="@+id/demoView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <com.faisal.FaisalActivity.DemoView
        android:id="@+id/demoView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above is my linear layout ignore the brackets i just removed them **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a setData method in your custom view and and an id to ur custom view in xml.

In the onCreate function of the activity class you could use the findViewById(ID OF CUSTOM VIEW) and set the data to the object. This way you can pass the data from the activiy to the view.

This a example of a [line chart](https://github.com/blessenm/LineChartDemo/blob/master/src/com/blessan/Demo.java) I created, here I pass an array of points to the linechart view which is a custom view.